# Uniform continuity of $\frac{1}{2} \sin{ \frac{x}{2}}- \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sin{ \frac{x}{2}}- \frac{1}{x}$ if $0<x \leqslant \pi$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$.

I took the sequences $$x_n=\frac{1}{n}$$ $$y_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$$

We have that $x_n-y_n \rightarrow 0$ but $$f(x_n)-f(y_n)=\frac{1}{2}( \sin{ \frac{1}{2n}}-\sin{ \frac{1}{2n^2}}) +(n^2-n)$$ does not converge to $0$.

Is this solution correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It might be easier to show that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\pi]$.  Can you see why?  Can you do that case?

Comment: That works.  Even easier, take $x_n =1/n$ and $y_n=2/n$.

Comment: you are right...yes i did that but i wanted to check the whole function..